# Add featuredImage in a Gatsby blog with MDX

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to add a featured image on my Gatsby blog but can't make it work. I tried several things found here and there but I just keep having this error message : `Field "featuredImage" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.`

Here is my blog structure :

```
src
 |- images
   |- house.jpeg
 | - pages
   |- actualites
     |- house.mdx
```

My `house.mdx` has the following frontmatter :

```
---
title: House
path: /house
date: 2019-01-29
featuredImage: ../../images/house.jpeg
---
```

And my `gatsby-plugin` looks like this :

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-resolve-src`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 800,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1200,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  ],
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... The http://localhost:8000/___graphql shows me my `featuredImage` but not the subfields for the image, so I guess it doesn't understand that my field is an image.

Could you please help me point what I am missing ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried by adding a `name`? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it didn't changed anything so I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to make it work.

The problem was that I was requesting `allSitePage` instead of `allMdx` in my graphQL. Now I can see my path as an image and request all its subfields.

Answer (score 1):

The issue usually comes from multiple sources:

- When there are differences in the naming of the strings paths (images in your case). For example, if you are looking for: `../../images/house.jpeg` but the image is placed or named `house.jpg` (not `jpeg`). Being relative paths, I assume that the issue comes from there. Try changing it to something like `./path/to/image.jpg`
- Check spelling
- Check plugins order
- Use GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`) to check the correct paths of the images by creating a specific query there.

References/useful resources:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13322
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/4123
- https://dev.to/stephencweiss/error-field-image-must-not-have-a-selection-since-type-string-has-no-subfields-3a76
- [https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/this-error-field-img-must-not-have-a-selection-since-type-string~05669aa2-8045-4875-a82b-c52e53df791e](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/this-error-field-img-must-not-have-a-selection-since-type-string%7E05669aa2-8045-4875-a82b-c52e53df791e)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw in other posts before posting here that usually the naming of the file or the path are the cause of the problems. So I checked multiple times and the name and path are correct. In the GraphQL playground, I don't have the possibility to query my field as an image. What do you mean with plugin order ? Does it have an incidence ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the relative paths? The `../..` to `./` or similar. The order of the plugins is also important, in your case is correct in the snippet (I assume in your project too) but it is a thing to check. In the playground, you can create another query to get the path of the image, that may be useful to check the paths.

Comment: Yes I tried changing the path, and also moved the `sharp` plugins to the top of the list, but I still get the same issue. I really don't know what to do, I'm stuck :/